# Flickr api search, can't get maximum number of results (=500) per page

Tags: python, flickr

I have tried to extract public images using flickr API and python. my snippet is as follows.

```
import flickrapi
import json
api_key="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
api_secret="xxxxxxxxxxxx"
flickr = flickrapi.FlickrAPI(api_key,api_secret,format='parsed-json')
photos = flickr.photos.search(text="whale",
                              has_geo=1,
                              per_page=500,
                              content_type=1,
                              extras='geo, date_taken',
                              place_id="Gdm6XV1TUb52hMbKtA")
```

this has resulted total 455 photos over two pages. 1st page contains only 250 and rest in the 2nd page. I don't know why it can't be put into single page (455<500). As per  [flickr documentation](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html) maximum photos that can be placed on one page is 500. I have tried this in [flickr search explorer](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/explore/flickr.photos.search)  and it showed all the results within one page. Any help is appreciated.